# Python - Sequence with repeating first element at the end

Tags: python, sequence

The purpose is to create closed polygons that need the first point added back at the end. And it needs to be done in a loop for several polygons thus I can't manually type it.
Hence the problem boils down to creating a sequence corresponding in which the first element is repeated at the end.

Using range I can get the sequence but I can't add the first element to the end:

```
s = [i for i in range(10)]
>>> [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

I need something in one line that outputs:

```
>>> [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0]
```

Comment: No need to wrap `range` in a comp.  Just use `list(range(10))` if you need to convert a range to a list.

Comment: What's the *input* for the task? It's unclear how your example generalizes. Right now I'd answer it with *"Simply write `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0]`"*.

Comment: The input is that I am creating polygons that need to be closed and I need to add the first point back at the end. And it needs to be done in a loop for several polygons thus I can't manually type it. I will edit the question. thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `+` operator to add a list to another list:

```
>>> [i for i in range(10)] + [0]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0]
```

Answer (score 1):

itertools.cycle will repeat an iterable indefinitely.  itertools.islice will yield the requested number of elements from an iterable.

Putting them together:

```
from itertools import cycle, islice
s = list(islice(cycle(range(10)), 11))
```

Answer (score 1):

Once you have `s` defined, you can create the sequence you need with

```py
s + [s[0]]
```

Full example:

```py
s = [i for i in range(10)]
print(s + [s[0]])
```

prints `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0]`.

Alternatively, you can modify `s` in-place with `s.append(s[0])`:

```py
s = [i for i in range(10)]
s.append(s[0])
print(s)
```

In one line:

```
list(range(10)) + [0]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like:

```
s = [i%10 for i in range(10 + 1)]
```

or adding it manually might be more safe

Answer (score 0):

In case `itertools` "is your friend" and you really must calculate in one line only you might use:

```
>>> length=10
>>> list(itertools.islice(itertools.chain.from_iterable(itertools.repeat(range(length),2)),0,length+1))
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0]
>>> length=20
>>> list(itertools.islice(itertools.chain.from_iterable(itertools.repeat(range(length),2)),0,length+1))
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 0]
```

This code does the following:

1. `itertools.repeat(range(length),2)` -> repeats the range iteration 2 times
2. `itertools.chain.from_iterable(iterator)` -> chains the two iterations
3. `itertools.islice(iterator,start,stop)` -> cuts out the target range
   (first element only of second range iteration)

Answer (score 0):

You could do the following if you have a reference to the sequence

```
s = list(range(10))
result = [*s,s[0]]
```

Or if you are always going to append "0"

```
result = [*range(10),0]
```

Answer (score -1):

**Be pythonic and use walrus!**

```
if sequence := [i for i in range(10)]:
    sequence += [sequence[0]]
```

Keeping your format and objective, this will add first element of the list to the end.